Parsing JSON5 in Groovy
I would like to parse a JSON5 object in Groovy, the reason why I want to use JSON5 is because I need to use the comment feature in groovy. So say for example, the JSON5 object would look like
{
  // comments 
"A":"123",
"B":"456"
}

This JSON5 object cannot be parsed by readJSON or JsonSlurper in Groovy.
I found there is a library in Python named JSON5 can do exactly what I needed, but the problem is my code is in Groovy.
So I am wondering if there is a library in Groovy can do this, or if there is any alternate decent way to handle it?

I don't see any implementation in java or groovy on official json5 site or github
However, there is a parser type LAX in groovy that allows comments.
import  groovy.json.*

def json = '''
{
  // comments 
  "A":"123",
  B: 456
}
'''

def parser = new JsonSlurper()
parser.type = JsonParserType.LAX
def obj = parser.parseText(json)
assert obj==[A:'123', B:456]

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonParserType.html#LAX
Beware - it's very unrestrictive. it allows keys and values without quotation.
